# Levenberg-Marquardt training

Tags: algorithms, neural-networks

I am trying to do simplified version of Levenberg-Marquardt alg. for NN with one hidden layer.
I found this article: [Efficient algorithm for training neural networks with one hidden layer](http://john.cs.olemiss.edu/~ychen/publications/conference/chen_ijcnn99.pdf)

I am not very math-skilled, so I have problem with calculating Jacobian partial derivates for matrix (7) in article (that is simplified Jacobian matrix). Does anonyone know this algorithm, or its implementation ? Classic (full) Levenberg-Marquardt is no use for me, because of large memory footprint.

Comment: It is not very easy indeed. I think instead of backpropagating each component at once, you have to perform backpropagation K times for each pattern p, each time for another output component k.

Comment: Yeah.. in classic LMA, I create Jacobian matrix by backpropagating from each output for each pattern, so matrix is really "huge" for big networks (and then calculate inverse... its not possible for me). This algorithm looks quite good in memory and speed of inverse, hovewer partial derivates are calculated how ? For classic LMA, I followed this description: http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~wilambm/pap/2011/K10149_C012.pdf, where is stated how to calculate partial derivates for full Jacobian matrix.. but how to change that to this modified version... ? I dont know :( I need everything in easy way :)

Comment: You have to regard each output as a network and perform backpropagation. Then, sum up the gradients over all training patterns.

Comment: So partial derivate from error is meant as sum of squared grads ? Than I calculate grads as for classis BP and just sum them, right ?

Comment: But don't sum up over k.

Comment: I summed gradients over patterns... if I run algorithm, I doesnt convert at all.. its just stucked at initial value as best. Output from alg. only increases error.

Comment: Yep, LMA is hard to implement even in standard version. I think I can't help you.

Comment: I got it working.. It can find solution for XOR problem and other related types... but I have problem with convergence rate. Sometimes it convert fast, sometimes it stuck.. do you know any solution to this ?

Comment: Usually people use trust-region algorithms to determine the step size along the update direction, e.g. line search.

Comment: Hm.. and even though if I use it for general problem, where BP convert with small values, LMAs error is "huge"...

Comment: Actually, LMA should converge to BP when it is near the goal. Do you adapt the mu?

Comment: I know it should be simmilar to BP for great error and to Newton for small error... but reality is different :( My mu adapt: if increase in error, discard weights and change mu (*v), otherwise change mu (/v). I also tried using bayesian regularization (proposed here: http://crsouza.blogspot.cz/2009/11/neural-network-learning-by-levenberg.html)